# communicating fpga <-> pc over ethernet

Tags: ethernet

how we will be able to tansfer the data from fpga to pc
whether we have to ping it aur there is any other solution

Answer (score 1):

The IEEE maintains all the ethernet standards in 802.3.  If you are programming hardware to communicate via ethernet, you need to follow those.

IP is not directly related to ethernet since it is at a higher layer and can use protocols other than ethernet on various layer-1 media.  Conversely, ethernet can transport higher layer protocols other than IP.

Comment: yes i am programming hardware (fpga) to communicate through ethernet

Comment: can just help me out how it will be done or how should i proceed

Comment: Programming questions belong on Stack Overflow, but you need the IEEE documentation to do it correctly.

Comment: what type of IEEE documentation??

Comment: The 802.3 documentation. There are various pieces to it, and it covers the various media you may use.

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of the various IEEE 802.3 standards. You needs to focus on the basics and the other ones you want to implement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.3

Comment: how can we tranfer data from fpga to pc using ethernet

Comment: do we need to ping both fpga and pc how we will be able to tranfer it

Comment: The moderators closed this question as off-topic. You are asking on the wrong forum. Stack Overflow is the programmer's forum, and there are many network-savvy programmers there.

Comment: Given the FPGA involvement i'd lean more towards electrical engineering. I would suggest posting a question over there with as much information as possible on what hardware and software you are using.